# What significance does the parameter "begin" of urls yotube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

For example:

http://o-o.preferred.telemexperu-lim1.v3.lscache6.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=N2EK-YTwdeU&sparams=algorithm%2Cburst%2Ccp%2Cfactor%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cms%2Cmt%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&fexp=919321%2C901027%2C907217%2C907335%2C921602%2C919306%2C919316%2C904455%2C919324%2C904452&key=yt1&algorithm=throttle-factor&mt=1337382014&ipbits=8&itag=35&sver=3&signature=94D9344CEF1C28BB9BB5F8C51C1F409BE39329B2.69CAFFDDF1556B2A83200F45F173F6E0FB8DE2CC&source=youtube&expire=1337407932&ms=au&ip=190.0.0.0&factor=1.25&cp=U0hSTFRLVV9ITENOMl9MRVlKOnVubENtTm5YaDRH&burst=40&id=ea8d708a77758947&ptchn=MARVEL&**begin=9724**&ptk=disney&cm2=1

when we advance the video (in some cases) the case that the youtube player sends the parameter begin ... but not the number of bytes, then what is?

You can do some testing here:

```
http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/6o1wind1iUc?version=2
```

Sorry for my english.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the number of milliseconds from the start.

Comment: Should this be a comment instead?

Comment: The question asked what it's for.  Not how to use it or anything.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if it still works? It doesn't work with ytdl, now.